# What are the changes want to do for marshmallow?Some content is not working in marshmallow.Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow

- Inside `try catch` block the query to whether the Username is there in db or not,is not working in Marshmallow. But working well in lower versions.*

  ```
  View.OnClickListener adduserOnClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

      try {
      fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFname);
      sname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextsname);
      email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
      code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextcode);
      Uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextuser);
      pwrd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextpass);
      //utype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerutype);

      String fname1 = fname.getText().toString();
      String lname1 = sname.getText().toString();
      String email1 = email.getText().toString();
      String code1 = code.getText().toString();
      String uname1 = Uname.getText().toString();
      String pswd1 = pwrd.getText().toString();
      String utype1 = "admin";


      if (fname1.equals("") {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter First Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      } else if (lname1.equals("") {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Second Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else if (email1.equals("") {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Email Id ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else if (code1.equals("") {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Authentication Code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else if (uname1.equals("") {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter User Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else if (pswd1.equals("") {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Password ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }else {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "1" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          try
          {
              sqlitedatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
              Cursor allrows1 = sqlitedatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.TableName+" WHERE "+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.UserName+"=='"+uname1+"'", null);

               System.out.println("COUNT : " + allrows1.getCount());
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "COUNT : " + allrows1.getCount() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              if(allrows1.getCount()<=0)
              {
                  exist= false;
              }
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Entering", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              allrows1.close();
              dbhelper.close();

          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          }
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "3" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


          if (exist) {


              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This User Name not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          } else {


                  dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                  sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                  dbhelper.insert(fname1, lname1, email1, code1, uname1, pswd1, utype1, sqlitedatabase);
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  dbhelper.close();
                  Registration.this.finish();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this, LoginActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);


          }
      }




      }catch (NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}


     }
  };
  ```

Comment: What exactly is happening in marshmallow?

Comment: 'exist' is not changing. Is because control is not entering into that try catch block. But working in lower version.

Comment: are you getting any exception in marshmallow? Debug and check

Comment: No exception is getting. No prob in debug mode control is entering into that. It is happening only when using with installed generated apk.